# ldap Authentication using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I am new in ldap .I am using ldap for authentication in  my application . I have 10 module in my application . I create a user in ldap and authenticate user using spring security and ldap successfully . But in new requirement i want to user access only 1st module , 3rd module and 8th module only . Can it is possible using ldap and spring security .I am using spring mvc project . Please suggest me thanks in advance .

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased and use a rolevoter for ldap